# Curvature Scalar in Riemannian Space

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose that ***R<sub>iklm</sub>=a(g<sub>il</sub>g<sub>km</sub>-g<sub>im</sub>g<sub>kl</sub> )*** on some four dimensional Riemannian space and ***a*** is a constant.
***Question:*** Show that for the curvature scalar we have ***R=-12a***.

What I know from calculating the Ricci curvature scalar is that it requires : ***1.*** The Dual Metric Tensor ***[g<sup>ij</sup>]***,which is the inverse of ***[g<sub>ij</sub>]***,the metric tensor and ***2.*** The Ricci Tensor(**R<sub>ij</sub>**).

Also,I use ***R<sub>iklm</sub>=sigma<sub>i</sub>(g<sub>i1</sub>R<sup>i</sup><sub>klm</sub>***) when calculating the Gaussian curvature.

So,I'm stuck and don't know how to approach this.

Thanks.

Comment: You only need that $R_{ij} = g^{kl} R_{kilj}$, $S = g^{ij}R_{ij}$ and $g^{ij }g_{jk} = \delta_{ik}$.

Comment: @JohnMa Thanks John,please elaborate.

Comment: Did you try to calculate $R_{ij}$ using the formula?

Comment: @JohnMa is $R_{ij}$ not for the Ricci Curvature Tensor?I'm not exactly sure what the main question needs.If the questions needs $R_{ij}$,the Ricci Curvature Tensor,i can only calculate it if I have the Riemann Curvature Tensor,which requires Christoffel Coefficients.Sorry,I'm totally lost here.

Comment: The Riemann curvature is given already: $R_{iklm} = a(g_{il}g_{km} - g_{im} g_{kl})$. Multiply $g^{il}$ on both sides and that gives you an expression for the Ricci curvature tensor. After that, multply $g^{km}$ on both sides.

Comment: @JohnMa ok,After multiplying both sides with $g^{il}$ on both sides I get $g^{il}R_{iklm}=a(g_{km}-g^{il}g_{im}g_{kl})$,since the inverse terms reduce to 1.Before I proceed with multiplying both sides by $g^{km}$,I don't see how this is getting to the curvature scalar R=-12a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will do the computation for the Ricci tensor $R_{ij}$ and leave the computation of scalar curvature to you.

You are given

$$R_{iklm} = a(g_{il}g_{km} - g_{im}g_{kl})$$

Multiplying $g^{il}$ on both sides and using $R_{km} = g^{il}R_{iklm}$, we have

$$\begin{split}
R_{km} = g^{il}R_{iklm} &= a g^{il}(g_{il}g_{km} - g_{im}g_{kl}) \\
&= a\big( (g^{il}g_{il}) g_{km} - (g^{il}g_{im})g_{kl}\big) \\
&= a\big( (g^{il}g_{il}) g_{km} - g_{km}\big)
\end{split}$$

Note that repeated indices are summed over, so
$$ g^{il}g_{il} = \sum_{i,l=1}^4 g^{il}g_{il} = \sum_{i=1}^4 \delta_{ii} = 4$$

since your manifold is of dimension four. Thus
$$R_{km} = a (4g_{km} - g_{km} )= 3a g_{km}$$

(Unfortunately if you continue you will find $R = 12a$. Probably we are using different convention of the Ricci tensor)

Comment: Thanks a lot John.You tried.I'm not sure how to get to R=-12a.Hopefully someone else will clarify this for me.

Comment: Do you understand my answer? @Jay

Comment: Partially.I don't see how $(g^{il}g_{im})g_{kl}$ became $g_{km}$.The rest is ok.

Comment: $g^{il}g_{im} = \delta_{lm}$, and $\delta_{lm} g_{kl} = g_{km}$@Jay

Comment: I see.The computation for the Riemann Tensor is pretty clear as you've shown.What's bugging me is the Scalar curvature's R=-12a.

Comment: Did you try to calculate $R = g^{km}R_{km}$? @Jay

Comment: So far I've only done Dual Metric Tensor and Ricci Tensor calculations with actual values,not by definition.That's what I need to understand to compute tensor contractions,to arrive at a scalar,R.

Comment: The answer is not far away... Note I have shown $R_{km} = 3ag_{km}$, so $R = g^{km} R_{km} = 3a g^{km}g_{km}$. What is this term (take a look at my answer again)? @Jay

Comment: I see that final term should be 12a on the RHS,by similar Kronecker delta properties.But how I get -12a?Your answer has helped a lot since it arrived to 12a.Perhaps I need to recheck the tensor theory.Thanks a lot John.

Comment: The difference in sign very likely are from the fact that I used a different convention of Ricci tensor as yours. @Jay That is, your definition might be $R_{im}=g^{kl}R_{iklm}$ instead.

Comment: True.I'm not sure why the proof requires -12a.